# Kinesis + AWS Lambda: monitoring Stream

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I just wonder what are good metrics to ensure the current number of lambda functions processing the stream are actually coping with the load.

With spark applications + Kinesis one can easily take a look at the throughput/current checkpoint of receivers within the stream.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda metrics you get out of the box with Lambda are not very useful for this.

We publish our own custom CloudWatch metric from our Lambda functions called 'SecondsBehind' which is the difference between the current timestamp and the approximateArrivalTimestamp from the kinesis record.

This shows us if we are starting to fall behind.